# Получить данные строки в виде таблицы в PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Всем привет!

1. Что я имею. Есть таблица Журнал(journal), которая хранит значения определённых параметров для
   определённой сущности в разное время и имеет вот такой вид:

| Id | entity_id | date | parameter1 | parameter2 | parameter3 | ... | parameterN | type_work |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-07-28 | 111 | 222 | 333 | ... | 1001 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2021-07-28 | 444 | 555 | 666 | ... | 1002 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 2021-07-28 | 777 | 888 | 999 | ... | 1003 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 2021-07-28 | 1 | 2 | 3 | ... | 1004 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 2021-07-29 | 4 | 5 | 6 | ... | 1005 | 1 |

то есть как вы видите для одной и той же сущности для одной и той же даты разные параметры могут
принимать разные значения в зависимости от типа работы type_work.

2. Также ещё есть и таблица Параметры(param), которая имеет следующий вид:

| Id | Title | Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Параметр 1 | parametr1 |
| 2 | Параметр 2 | parametr2 |
| 3 | Параметр 3 | parametr3 |
| . | .......... | ......... |
| N | Параметр N | parametrN |

3. Что мне нужно:

я сейчас пишу хранимую функцию, которая на входа принимает 2 параметра:

- Id сущности, то есть entity_id
- дату, то есть date

мне нужно по дате и по Id сущности взять данные из таблицы Журнала(journal)
и положить её в результирующую таблицу result_data, которая должна будет иметь
следующий вид (например для entity_id = 1 и date = '2021-07-28'):

```
|   Id   | entity_id |    date    | type_work | param_id | value |
| ------ | --------- | ---------- | --------- | -------- | ----- |
|    1   |     1     | 2021-07-28 |     1     |     1    |  111  |
|    2   |     1     | 2021-07-28 |     1     |     2    |  222  |
|    3   |     1     | 2021-07-28 |     1     |     3    |  333  |
| ...... | ......... | .......... | ......... | ........ | ..... |
|    N   |     1     | 2021-07-28 |     1     |     N    |  1001 |
|   N+1  |     1     | 2021-07-28 |     2     |     1    |  444  |
|   N+2  |     1     | 2021-07-28 |     2     |     2    |  555  |
|   N+3  |     1     | 2021-07-28 |     2     |     3    |  666  |
| ...... | ......... | .......... | ......... | ........ | ..... |
|    2N  |     1     | 2021-07-28 |     2     |    N     |  1002 |
|   2N+1 |     1     | 2021-07-28 |     3     |    1     |  777  |
|   2N+2 |     1     | 2021-07-28 |     3     |    2     |  888  |
|   2N+3 |     1     | 2021-07-28 |     3     |    3     |  999  |
| ...... | ......... | .......... | ......... | ........ | ..... |
|    3N  |     1     | 2021-07-28 |     3     |    N     |  1003 |
```

То есть как видите группировка происходит по entity_id, date и type_work. То есть
в результирующей таблице result_data есть индекс уникальности для строчки по полям
entity_id, date, type_work, то есть не может быть ни одной строчки с одинаковым набором данных полей.

Кроме того в запросе мне нужно иметь возможность передать те параметры из таблицы Журнал(journal), которые
я хочу добавить в результирующую таблицы. То есть, например, хочу добавлять только параметры parameter1,
parameter2, parameter3 - значит добавляю только их.

И есть важное ограничение! Тимлид сказал мне делать это всё без циклов. В текущей реализации я использую
конструкцию вида

```
FOR temprow IN
SELECT * FROM 
....
LOOP
...
END LOOP;
```

Так вот мне нужно без цикла.

Я нашёл одно решение, которое мне некоторым образом помогло:

```
select * from
jsonb_each
(
    (select to_jsonb(j.*) from journal j where j.id = 1)
) s
```

Оно выводит результат такого вида:

```
|     key    |    value   |
| ---------- | ---------- |
|     Id     |     1      |
| entity_id  |     1      |
|    date    | 2021-07-28 |
| parameter1 |     111    |
| parameter2 |     222    |
| parameter3 |     333    |
| .......... | .......... |
| parameterN |    1001    |
| type_work  |      1     |
```

Но это только для одной записи для одного типа работы type_work! А как мне также выбрать записи по entity_id, date(дате) и type_work?
Ведь для разных типов работ у одной и той же сущности для одной и той же даты значения параметров могут быть разные.

Может быть хоть какие-нибудь идеи есть на это счёт? Как это делается вообще? Я могу скинуть в принципе и рабочий код с циклом как я сделал,
если нужно. Но в том то и дело, что сделать всё нужно БЕЗ ЦИКЛА.

Заранее спасибо всем кто ответит!

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT
    j.entity_id,
    j.date,
    j.type_work,
    p.id,
    CASE
      WHEN p.code = 'parametr1' THEN j.parameter1
      WHEN p.code = 'parametr2' THEN j.parameter2
      WHEN p.code = 'parametr3' THEN j.parameter3
      WHEN p.code = 'parametr4' THEN j.parameter4
   END as value
FROM journal AS j
  CROSS JOIN param AS p
WHERE j.date = '2021-07-28'
```

Решение по ссылке: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5cbf40/1

Comment: Спасибо огромное!